# Given a matrix, cell is call good cell if row divides column

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

Given a n*m matrix, a cell is called good cell if row number (i) divides column number (j)

Example :
   2*3 matrix => cells are {1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3} from which good cells can be defined as {1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,2}

So the output is 4

I have figure out the logic for this, row 1 has all cells as good cells, row 2 has m/2 good cells, row 3 has m/3 good cells. (I am using just the integer dividend)

```
 m/1 + m/2 + m/3 + ........ + m/n;
```

For which my code looks like =>

```
long count=1;
 long answer = 0;
 while(count<=n){
    answer=answer + m/count;
    count++;
 }
```

But this code is getting timed out when I am submitting my solution. Need help to find better approach for this.
PS: Coding challenge is already over.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You also may want to post a URL of the contest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```cs
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < m; j += i) // j += i will save unwanted loops
   {
       // rest of your logic  
   }
}
```

As the value of `i` gets higher and higher nested loop will become more efficient

**edit**

The below code will be more efficient & correct than above. **Now nested loop starts with the value of `i` instead of 0**

```cs
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
   for(int j = i; j < m; j += i) //j = i & j += i will save unwanted loops
   {
       // rest of your logic  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as noted by n pronouns m this post **incorrect** since it only considers the case n==m

You may have a look at the [Dirichlet divisor problem](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C10%2C14%2C16%2C20&sort=&language=&go=Search)

One attempt is the formula of Benoit Cloitre:

(below octave implem)

```
function s = sumit(n)
    s = 0;
    for i = 1:n
        s += floor(n/i);
    end
end
n = 1e6
expect = sumit(n)

%A006218
u = floor(sqrt(n));
res = 2*sum(floor(n./(1:u))) - u^2
```

Where you avoid summing quite some terms.

Comment: Note the input for the OP problem is *two* numbers.

Comment: thx for noting the invalidity of this answer. I am not deleting it because maybe hint to dirichlet keyword may help.